# Multiple Prompt Values for Microsoft Identity Endpoint

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is there a way to include both login and consent prompts via Microsoft Identity platform?

The docs do NOT explicitly mention support for multiple prompt values:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

I attempted this PowerShell script with space delimited login and consent values. The space is encoded as "%20" e.g., prompt=login%20consent.

```bsh
$clientId = "MyClientId

Start-Process "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=$clientId&scope=openid%20profile%20https://ads.microsoft.com/ads.manage%20offline_access&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient&state=ClientStateGoesHere&prompt=login%20consent"

$code = Read-Host "Grant consent in the browser, and then enter the code here (see ?code=UseThisCode&...)"
Write-Output "code: " $code  
$response = Invoke-WebRequest https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded -Method POST -Body "client_id=$clientId&scope=https://ads.microsoft.com/ads.manage%20offline_access&code=$code&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Fcommon%2Foauth2%2Fnativeclient"

$oauthTokens = ($response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json)  
Write-Output "Access token: " $oauthTokens.access_token  
Write-Output "Access token expires in: " $oauthTokens.expires_in  
Write-Output "Refresh token: " $oauthTokens.refresh_token
```

This results in an unsupported prompt error:

```
Request Id: 9e072f53-23f2-4317-9dda-240e18c15c00
Correlation Id: f7a29334-c4e3-40d4-9810-c22f6a78c4d9
Timestamp: 2020-01-31T15:57:50Z
Message: AADSTS90023: Unsupported 'prompt' value.
```

Via the live endpoint I can include space delimited login and consent prompts. The space is encoded as "%20" e.g., prompt=login%20consent. This PowerShell script prompts for login and consent as expected.

```bsh
$clientId = "MyClientId"

Start-Process "https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=$clientId&scope=bingads.manage&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf&prompt=login%20consent"

$code = Read-Host "Grant consent in the browser, and then enter the code here (see ?code=UseThisCode&...)"

$response = Invoke-WebRequest https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded -Method POST -Body "client_id=$clientId&scope=bingads.manage&code=$code&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.live.com%2Foauth20_desktop.srf"

$oauthTokens = ($response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json)  
Write-Output "Access token: " $oauthTokens.access_token  
Write-Output "Access token expires in: " $oauthTokens.expires_in  
Write-Output "Refresh token: " $oauthTokens.refresh_token
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error shows, it's **unsupported** to set both login and consent prompts currently.

According to design principles, when your resources are integrated with Azure Active Directory, permissions to access them is requested using the Azure AD consent framework.

This results in a consent prompt being shown the first time an application is used, which is often a **one-time operation**.

So there is no need to add consent prompt into the request to trigger the OAuth consent dialog each time after the user signs in.

Forcing a username and password might make sense, but forcing consent after every login is not.

Comment: The common identity endpoint also supports consumers i.e., personal Microsoft account. Our clients are looking for flexibility here. Thanks